# Haskell PrintF formatting

Tags: haskell

I have a function `fnAvg` that produces a float, that I want to `show`, which works up until I try to format it using printf. I'm looking to get 1dp, and looking around I use "%.1f" and printf to get there:

`show ( printf "%.1f" fnAvg film)`

I get no instance for (PrintFArg Film).

I've tried moving brackets around, or making it `show (printf "%.1f" (fnAvg Film))` but this leads to getting no instance errors for show as well. Have I made a mistake or is it a simple formatting issue?

EDIT:

The reason for the show is that it's part of a bigger list:

`[... ++ printf "%.1f" (show (fnAvg film)) ]`

I came up with the above syntax, but it outputs a PrintF.printf bad argument error.

Comment: A thought, do I use printf on the outside instead of show?

Comment: I don't think there's any need for show here.

Comment: It's part of a bigger function, it's in a list thats being put together so it needs string values.

Comment: @Chillo, can you please post [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org)? This will help us to help you.

Comment: Your example looks good except the `show`, have you tried without that.

Comment: Great it works without show! Thank you, I didn't know it could replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original version had an extraneous `show` and was passing `fnArg` and `film` as two separate parameters to `printf`. `printf` has a weird system to support variable arguments so that is why you got an odd error.

Your second version tried to `show` the `float`, which results in passing a variable of type `String` into a `0.1f` format, which does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is expecting one argument, but you've given it two. Also, `show` is not necessary here.

Perhaps you want `printf "%.1f" (fnAvg film)`?

Comment: this is not the reason for `no instance for PrintFArg Film` like error

Comment: Thanks, resolved it now. Film is the argument for fnAvg.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the wonky initial answer - it was clear once the additional context was provided!